# SQL Server 2008 Trigger which sends email

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Does anyone know why this wouldn't work?  It's a trigger which checks the value of a field on insert and update and sends an email with the value of an id column from the offending row.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[DB]
ON [dbo].[table]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM inserted WHERE value = 5)
   BEGIN
      EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
        @recipients = 'me@derp.com', 
        @profile_name = 'MailProfile',
        @subject = 'DB.dbo.table trigger', 
        @body = '',
        @execute_query_database = 'DB',
        @query = 'USE DB SET NOCOUNT ON SELECT id FROM dbo.table WHERE value = 5';
   END
END
```

The problem seems to be the @query in the sp_send_dbmail function.  When I manually try triggering it I receive the following error;

```
No row was updated.
The data in row x was not committed.
Error Source: .Net SqlClient Data Provider.
Error Message:  Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.
Correct the errors and retry or press ESC to cancel the change(s).
```

When I remove @execute_query_database and @query and add some plain text to the @body var the trigger works and I receive an email.

I've also tried changing the @query value to something really simple e.g. `SELECT "Test" as test` but this didn't help.

I'm completely new to triggers so if the problem is painfully obvious... apologies :)

Comment: You shoudl not send an emal from a trigger. YOu shoudl put the information about the email into a staging table and havea  job that sends those emails every few minutes. If you have emails in a trigger and the email server goes down, you will not be able to add, update or delrte records on thr table until the email is back up.

Comment: Bloody good point HLGEM! :)  What about wrapping the email in a try catch?

Comment: That won;t work. Really you need to put the information about the email in a staging table and then havea job that runs every five minutes ro so that sends out the emails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need semi-colons:

```
@query = 'USE DB; SET NOCOUNT ON; SELECT id FROM dbo.table WHERE value = 5;';
```

Comment: Thanks Tab.  I've tried but I'm getting the same timeout error.  I've also noticed that SQL becomes unresponsive after a failed trigger.  I can't run any further queries until I restart SQL Server.  There also doesn't seem to be anything useful in the error logs.  Any more thoughts?

Comment: HLGEM is correct about the best practice for sending email from a trigger.  However, I am treating the question as academic.  If you just want to fix the problem you should do it his way.  That said, my next step would be to see if I can execute just the EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail statement by itself.  If it timesout, I would enlist a DBA and/or a network admin to help investigate why it isn't working.

Comment: I probably will end up storing the info in a separate table and running a job to email it BUT I'd still like to know why it's not working.  I previously tried running the SP_SEND_DBMAIL function on it's own outside of the trigger and it works without error.

Comment: When you ran it on its own did you give every parameter the exact same values that you are giving it in the trigger?  If so, next step would be to start a profiler trace to see exactly which command is timing out.  Maybe it's credentials-related, so you should test for that as well.

Comment: Yeah I basically took the command straight out of the existing trigger and tried running it.  I'll look into profiling and let you know what comes from that.

Comment: I eventually got to the bottom of it but cannot remember now exactly what it was.  I know it was something stupid though :)  Thanks for your help and sorry for the late acceptance.